# What is the difference if I create a UILabel as part of my LoadView() compared to creating a fileprivate uilabel?

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit, ios-autolayout

I have always been programmatically building my UI and recently I was starting to learn more about loadView(). I realized that when I used loadView() I would write code this way:

```
 override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()
    let EarningsView = UIView()
    let EarningsLabel = UILabel()
    EarningsView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    EarningsLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let earningsText = NSAttributedString(string: "My Earnings", attributes: self.stringAttrib)
    EarningsLabel.attributedText = earningsText
    EarningsLabel.textColor = .black
    EarningsLabel.backgroundColor = .white

    EarningsView.addSubview(EarningsLabel)
    EarningsView.addViewBorder(borderColor: UIColor.black.cgColor, borderWith: 0.5, borderCornerRadius: 0.0)
    EarningsView.backgroundColor = .white

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        EarningsView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentStack.widthAnchor),
        EarningsView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentStack.topAnchor),
        EarningsView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentStack.centerXAnchor), 

    view.addSubview(EarningsView)

  }
```

As Compared to how I have always written it:

```
fileprivate lazy var earningsView : UIView = {

    var view = UIView()
    let EarningsLabel = UILabel()

    EarningsLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let earningsText = NSAttributedString(string: "My Earnings", attributes: self.stringAttrib)
    EarningsLabel.attributedText = earningsText
    EarningsLabel.textColor = .black
    EarningsLabel.backgroundColor = .white

    view.addSubview(EarningsLabel)
    view.addViewBorder(borderColor: UIColor.black.cgColor, borderWith: 0.5, borderCornerRadius: 0.0)
    view.backgroundColor = .white

    view.addSubview(EarningsLabel)
    return view
}()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.addSubview(earningsView)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

        earningsView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor),
        earningsView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor),
        earningsView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.widthAnchor),
        earningsView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.heightAnchor,multiplier: 0.20),


    ])
```

Is one way better than the other? Or is this more of a personal preference.

Comment: Never ever call `super.loadView()`. The only reason to call `loadView` is to give the view controller’s main view some special class. You are not, so don’t.

Comment: Search for `loadview vs viewdidload` ... lots and lots of articles / blog posts / discussions.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the loadView() and viewDidLoad() has to do with lifecycle events. Essentially everything happens in order and certain things have to happen at specific times. For example if you attempt to give parent view controller a class after it's been loaded then you'll run into issues. The fix for that is to use loadView() and add it there. Essentially making your class, function, or whatever happen as a part of loading the view, before it's presented.

Typically people have a better understanding when you consider how the view appears with its associated methods as an example.

#### **viewWillAppear()**

- It's much easier to set up the view in this method than setting it up after the fact. You really only want to do that with processes that are fast and don't hang up the application.

#### **viewDidAppear()**

- Attempting to set something on the view here requires that you use the main thread and pass everything else to a background thread.

The same lifecycle concept applies to loading. It's also worth noting that you probably shouldn't be using loadView on any modern applications that are built-in Interface Builder. It's typically more useful to use `loadView()` when working with manually created views granted it won't make much of a difference, but using viewDidLoad() can present certain challenges at times, although rarely.